# /var/lib/dpkg/available MISSING

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, software-installation, downloads

I get the error message:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/available missing.
```

That is a problem, I realize, as it is not possible to download or update anything at all. Not keen on installing a new system - how is this fixable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just wondering, is this the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

Usually this error is harmless. If you still want to recreate `/var/lib/dpkg/available` with the contents, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'
```

From `man dpkg`:

```
--merge-avail

    With  action  --merge-avail,  old   information   is  combined   with  information  from  Packages-file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed my `/var/lib/dpkg/available` via

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

and an installation is possible.

Simply run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo dselect update
```

If the installation isn't possible, download the `dselect` package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dselect&searchon=names) and install the package via the command below. I have used the 64-bit version for Trusty in my example

```
cd
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dselect_1.17.5ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dselect_1.17.5ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb
```

---

The steps via

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update
```

doesn't recreates the content in `/var/lib/dpkg/available` in my case

---

From `man dpkg`

```
--clear-avail
    Erase the existing information about what packages are available.
```

From `man dselect`

```
update
    Refresh the available packages database.
```

Comment: I think you should retain `sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: This was my first idea, doesn't works. :\

Comment: you mean `sudo apt-get update` doesn't work? Mine works though!

Comment: The command works, but `/var/lib/dpkg/available` is still empty after that.