# Ubuntu 16.10 Software Center Not Removing Apps

Tags: software-center, 16.10

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. Now in the Software Center, I can install apps as I could previously, but I can't remove them anymore. I tried installing the old Ubuntu Software Center, but the problem remains; apps install fine, but fail to remove. In the new software center, after I select remove and input my password, it looks like it's about to do something, but then the remove button remains there and the app is still installed. If I try to remove something from the old software center, it gives a message reading,

> Package operation failed

and then under the details tab, it reads,

> installArchives() failed:dpkg: error: failed to open package info file
>   '/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: how about answers in this question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/667697