# Can't install software update on ubuntu 18.04. Face error with the upgrade command

Tags: upgrade

I face an error when I try to upgrade ubuntu 18.04. 
As always, I tried to install last software update on Ubuntu, I run the `sudo apt update` command which works well and when I run the `sudo apt upgrade` command I faced an error. I tried many solutions find here but those solutions do not solve my problem. Here is the error

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states
```

Comment: Can you add to our question, the output of `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/var/lib/dpkg/available MISSING](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667697/var-lib-dpkg-available-missing)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

This will give you your default config for dpkg

Comment: I found a solution here. 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/667697/var-lib-dpkg-available-missing'

Comment: Does this one work

Comment: @efthialex no the command is to make a backup